# Is it possible to use @AutoValue with Guice's FactoryModuleBuilder?

Tags: guice, auto-value

Per https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject,

Lets say I have an interface `A`, implementing class `AImpl` and another interface `AFactory` that I use with the FactoryModuleBuilder -

```
..

install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(A.class, AImpl.class)
    .build(AFactory.class)
);

..
```

Is it possible to use [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) for `AImpl`? My concern is then `AImpl` would be abstract and the factory module won't be able to instantiate it. And if I pass `AutoValue_AImpl` instead to the factory module, it won't have the `@Assisted*` annotations on it.

Comment: I tried. @AssistedInject cannot be put on a method other than constructor. So I cannot use it in `AImpl`. And I don't have access to the constructor in `AutoValue_AImpl`, since that is generated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages don't work well together; more to the point, there is *no reason* you should use these two features together.

AutoValue typically creates *data objects* or *value objects*, with robust `equals` and `hashCode` implementations. Objects created from AutoValue are immutable, with static factory methods instead of constructors; there's no room or reason for Guice-provided dependencies. See [the docs](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value):

> Using AutoValue limits your public creation API to static factory methods, not constructors. See Effective Java Item 1 for several reasons this is usually a good idea anyway.
>
> AutoValue does not and will not support creating mutable value types. (We may consider adding support for withField-style methods, which return a new immutable copy of the original instance with one field value changed.)

FactoryModuleBuilder typically creates factories for objects that have some injected dependencies and some manually-specified dependencies. As above, AutoValue packages should never fit this description.

Of course, you may use constants accessible from Guice to build out your value objects; however, you'll need to do this by writing your own lightweight factory object that maps injectable parameters to your value object's methods as needed.